# How to run a bash script for a certain amount of time?

Tags: bash, shell

I want my script to run for a certain amount of time, just like this:

```
timeout 10s ./script
```

However, I want to integrate the command within my script

```
for a in {a..z};
do
  for b in {a..z};
  do
  echo "$a$b"
  done
done
```

I've tried putting the timeout command in the for loop, but it doesn't work. How do use the timeout command in the script?

Comment: this script will take no time to run, the timeout won't be triggered.  You can replace the loops with `echo {a..z}{a..z}`.

Comment: yes but what if i want to end the script in 2s instead of 10s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a background process and your own timer. It's not guaranteed to last exactly 10 seconds, but it will usually be close.

```
for a in {a..z};
do
  for b in {a..z};
  do
  echo "$a$b"
  done
done &
sleep 10;
kill ${!}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
timeout 2s bash -c 'for a in {a..z};
do
  for b in {a..z};
  do
  echo "$a$b"
  done
done'
```

is one way to do it but as @karafka already mentioned you can avoid for loop by doing

```
timeout 2s echo {a..z}{a..z} | sed 's/[[:blank:]]/\n/g'
```

or even

```
timeout 2s printf "%s\n" {a..z}{a..z}
```

Comment: for one element per line, perhaps better use `printf "%s\n" {a..z}{a..z} `

Comment: Beat me to it ! Thankyou @karakfa . Updated !!